# Java store and read byte array from property file yaml

Tags: java, arrays, spring, yaml

I am working on an application that reads data from a database. There are already encrypted entries in the DB. I have the key as a byte array and want to load it from a yaml file.

Is there a way i can populate an array like this

```
private static final byte[] iv = { 13, -11, -88, 20, -110, 113, -2, -8, -15, -99, -23, -10, -10, -74, 1, 11 }
```

Directly from a yaml file?

yaml file:

```
iv: 13,-11,-88
```

Since I cannot autowire the class where I need to use the key, i cannot use @value annotation (from my understanding). So I was looking to use a util class like so:

```
public static byte[] getKeyFor(Class type) {
    return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("iv");
}
```

Comment: please, show your simple yaml file for example

Comment: @BSeitkazin I'll edit it into the question, but my problem is, that the getProperty() method on application context (spring) only returns string

Comment: yeah, that is right behaviour. you just should parse that string to array or list of bytes by yourself

Comment: @BSeitkazin is there any util I can use to directly convert the string to byte array?

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below should work:

```
application.yml:

iv: 12,32,12,32
```

In the class where you want the values, bind it like below:

```
@Value("${iv}") byte[] iv;
```

Comment: i was looking for something like that, there is one more problem. I cannot autowire the respective class, so I cannot use @value annotation. I was looking to use a util class like I edited in my question now.

Comment: Any reason you can't autowire the class? In that case, autowire this in a bean which is being created by Spring in your application, get that bean from application context and then get this byte array from that bean.

Answer (score 0):

You got some string with your byte data in `String` format.

```
String iv = someCall(); //"13, -11, -88, 20, -110, 113, -2, -8, -15, -99, -23"
String[] byteStrings = iv.split(",");
byte[] byteData = new byte[byteStrings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++){
    byteData[i] = Byte.parseByte(byteStrings[i], 8); 
}
```